# How can I create a function that iterates through a multidimentional array, identifies which array of numbers is even, and returns the even array?

Tags: javascript, function, multidimensional-array

I am a n00b and I have this challenge to do:

**Instructions**

Write a function named getValidPassword that takes a two dimensional array as parameter.

Each entry in the array represents a passcode. You need to find the passcode that has no odd digits and return it from your function.
Here's an example:

```
var loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3, 8],
    [4, 3, 2, 3, 9]
];

getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes) // returns the array: [2, 6, 0, 8]
```

I have now been stuck on this for one day - I've looked for solutions and tried them but none seems to be getting it right.

Here's what I tried:

```
var loggedPasscodes = [
    [1, 4, 4, 2],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 1],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3],
    [4, 1, 4, 8],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [6, 2, 8, 1]
];




// ------ TRY 1: ------


var getValidPassword = function (arr){
    
    for(var i = 0; i < loggedPasscodes.length; i++){
        var loggedPasscodesItem = loggedPasscodes[i].join('');          //This turns the array into a string, as we can see below:
            console.log('loggedPasscodes items ' + i + ' :' + loggedPasscodesItem);
      
        
            console.log('typeof loggedPasscodesItem: ' + typeof loggedPasscodesItem );
        
//How can I turn a string into an array? Doesnt make sense, as I can only evaluate if elements of array are even if I turn them into numbers.
        
//The below for loop enters the elements of each array, and returns numbers. 

        for(var j = 0; j < loggedPasscodes[i].length; j++){
           console.log('loggedPasscodes ' + [i] + ':' + loggedPasscodes[i][j]); 

//loggedPasscodes[i][j] gives us each of the numbers.
            
            
            if(loggedPasscodes[i] >= '0') && (loggedPasscodes[i][j] % 2 === 0)) {
                
            var eachPasscodeString = loggedPasscodes[i];
             
            var eachArray = Array.from(eachPasscodeString, Number);
                console.log('eachArray ' + i + ': ' + eachArray);
          
            } else if ((loggedPasscodes[i) >= '1') && (loggedPasscodes[i][j] % 2 ===0)){
                console.log('eachArray ' + i + ': ' + eachArray);

            }
                
        }
    }
};

getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes);
```

**What I thought would be a good solution would be  to lookup if loggedPasscodes[i][j] are even and also to see if they belong to the same array by checking if loggedPasscodes[i] is the same for each of them - if they match both requirements, return them in an array form**

The above gave me a warning in the else if statement saying that eachArray is out of scope...

Maybe the answer is go through the separate numbers and evaluate if they are even. If they are even, .slice() the rows by specifying the length of each of the arrays that contains that sequence of numbers, and by doing so, return that number sequence as an array (.push() to a new array), so we can reach the result of array of [2,6,0,8]?

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: _"and also to see if they belong to the same array by checking if loggedPasscodes[i] is the same for each of them"_ - that makes rather little sense. You should loop over the first array dimension first, those _are_ your passcodes. And then you check if each of the number in the _current_ passcode is true, and if so, you return that passcode. That does not involve any _additional_ check of the sort you mentioned, you get that "built-in" already, by looping over the top dimension first.

Comment: You need to fix some syntax errors in your code, for example: in `if(loggedPasscodes[i] >= '0') && (loggedPasscodes[i][j] % 2 === 0)) {` most of your if-statement is outside of the if-parentheses. And fix your "out of scope" error.

Comment: What should be the response if several lines of your loggedPasscodes match your criteria? should they be combined in the output array or stop at the first valid one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a number is even you could use the [Remainder Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) `%`:

```js
// Function to check if a passed n Number is even.
// Retuns Boolean
const isEven = n => !(n % 2);
```

To check if **all** array values match a specific condition use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
[2,0,6,8].every(isEven);   // true
[9,0,6,8].every(isEven);   // false
```

To get a filtered Array use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
arr.filter(pwd => pwd.every(isEven))
```

The above will return an array with multiple valid passwords (arrays).
To get only **one** result (a single valid password) use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
arr.find(pwd => pwd.every(isEven))
```

Example: ***(Spoiler alert!)***

```js
const isEven = n => !(n % 2);

const getValidPassword = arr => arr.find(pwd => pwd.every(isEven));

var loggedPasscodes =[
    [1, 4, 4, 1],
    [1, 2, 3, 1],
    [2, 6, 0, 8],
    [5, 5, 5, 5],
    [4, 3, 4, 3, 8],
    [4, 3, 2, 3, 9]
];

console.log(getValidPassword(loggedPasscodes));
```

Comment: `const isEven = n => !(n&1);` boolean operator and is faster...

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Thank you for your great explanation and code!! It's sooo close:I just need to present the result under one array, like so: [2, 6, 0, 8]. 
I tried the push method into a single dimention array, but that doesnt seem to be working either.. What am I missing?

Comment: You're very welcome @JRPCRD edited my answer above. To get only a single one (the first one that is valid) use `.find()` instead of `filter()`. Or, when using filter, to get a specific index use the desired index like `myValidPasswords[0]; // the first valid or undefined`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Amazing, it worked!! Thank you so much for your clear explanation and help with this. I was so stuck with the exercise and on the methods I was trying, I couldn't find other way that fit! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

If there is always only one valid array, you can use that:

*But if there is more than one valid the next others are ignored,

otherwise (if there is none) this function return* `undefined`

```js
const isEven = n => !(n&1); // check last bit

const getValidPassword = (arr2D) => 
    {
    let resp = arr2D.find( pwd => pwd.every(isEven)); 
    return !!resp ? [...resp] : undefined;  
    }

const  loggedPasscodes = 
    [ [ 1, 4, 4, 1 ] 
    , [ 1, 2, 3, 1 ] 
    , [ 2, 6, 0, 8 ] 
    , [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ] 
    , [ 4, 3, 4, 3, 8 ] 
    , [ 4, 3, 2, 3, 9 ] 
    ];

console.log( getValidPassword( loggedPasscodes ));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```